# For object types like [System.String], what are the options called after the :: and how would I list all available options?

Tags: powershell

I don't know the terminology for it, but with object types in PowerShell such as `[System.String]`, `[System.IO.File]`, etc. usually there are basically methods and properties for the object type, which are accessible with a double colon ("::"), like this:

```
[System.String]::Format($x, $y, $z)
[System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite
```

For the above examples, what would the items `Format()` and `ReadWrite` be called? Are they properties, methods, etc?

The only way I know how to see them is by typing out the typename (`[System.String]::`), then tabbing through the list until I find what I'm looking for (or the dropdown list in VS Code).

My question is, how would I get the full list of options available for a specified type? With other objects, you can use `Get-Member` but when I run that on an object type like above, it returns a bunch of different methods/properties than what I'm asking about.

Comment: They are either properties, or methods. If it is a property it does not need brackets like '()' at the end. You can find all properties and methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0). The string type is borrowed from the underlying .NET Framework. The `::` is the same as the `.` in C# or VB. Different Syntax but same thing.

Comment: @Max how would I get a list of the available properties/methods using powershell?

Comment: Simply by calling `[string] | Get-Member`, but I'd recommend using the Microsoft documentation as is explains the properties and methods.

Comment: @Max I said in the question that I tried that, but it returns different properties/methods. For example, `[System.String]` has a `[System.String]::Empty` property and a `[System.String]::Copy()` method, but when you run `[string] | get-member` there is no `Empty` property and no `Copy()` method.

Comment: Because it is not a member of the string type but a static method. Just call `[system.string] | Get-Member -Static -Type method`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called *static members*. Both methods and attributes are available.

In most cases, to use a .Net class' member, one needs to create an object first, then access the member via said object. Static members are an exception to the rule. One can [use those](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods?view=powershell-7.3) right via the class without creating an object.

As for how to find out class members, look into Microsoft .Net documentation. Here's for example [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0). For quick searches, the .Net [API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/).

Comment: Thanks, I use the .Net docs to look up those members frequently, I was just wondering if there's a way to get a list of them from the powershell terminal. Edit: According to the link you sent, the way to do it is `[System.Environment] | Get-Member -Static`

Comment: @jerdub1993, maybe also good to know is that you might also have [static members in a *custom* class](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes#static-attribute)